# Why is left side constant omitted when solving differential equation using separation method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What happened to the left side constant when Solving differential equation using separation method?

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y$$
$$\frac{dy}{y}=dx$$

$$\int\frac{dy}{y}=\int dx$$
$$ln\left(\left|y\right|\right)=x+C_2$$
$$y=e^{x+C_2}=Ce^x$$

However,

$$\int \:1dx=x+C_2$$

and

$$\int \frac{1}{y}dy=\ln \left|y\right|+C_1$$

So I would write:

\begin{align*}
 ln\left(\left|y\right|\right)+C_1&=x+C_2\\
 ln\left(\left|y\right|\right)&=x+C_2-C_1\\
 \left|y\right|&=e^{x+C_2-C_1}
\end{align*}

So what happened to $C_1$ ?

Also, why $e^{x+C_2}=e^{C_2}e^x$ is equal to $Ce^x$ ?

Finally, why the solution is  $y=Ce^x$ not $y=-Ce^x$ if $C$ is arbitrary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants are arbitrary. You can call $C_2=C_2-C_1$, or $C=e^{C_2}$, without loss of generality. They are defined with a boundary condition, until then the solution works for every number you plug in for $C_1$, $C_2$ or $C$.

Comment: So can I say that for $y'=y$ , $y=-^$ is as true as $y=^$ ?

Comment: @TSR Yes, basically.